# What is the best model selection method for high-dimensional linear regression?

Tags: regression, cross-validation, feature-selection, model-selection, lasso

Model selection (best subset selection) in linear regression is quite important in many applications. Among the methods belonging to different frameworks such as information criterion, hypothesis testing, and cross-validation, is there any way to tell what method is the best? Or if someone can direct to some literature that has done some comparative analysis on the performance of these methods! Especially if we focus on high-dimensional sparse linear regression models.

Comment: Model selection may not always have the same aim. Particularly optimal prediction quality may not be the ultimate aim, and in some applications we may be interested in bringing down the number of variables more than required for prediction quality (for example because future data collection is more expensive with more variables). Different methods may be good for different aims.

Comment: Also performance comparison will depend on a number of issues such as how close to zero true nonzero coefficients actually are and the distribution of their values, whether and in which way model assumptions are violated, existing background information potentially to be encoded in prior probabilities for inclusion etc.